# How does the background to an html element occupy the entire viewport?

Tags: html, css, semantics

Without even providing any height to the `html` element, how does the `background` cover the entire viewport. When I inspect the computed height of the `html` element it's just `8px` which is because of the `margin` that `body` gets from user agent stylesheet.

```css
html {
  background: hotpink;
}
```

This even happens if you give a background to `body: {background: hotpink}` when the computed height of `body` is `0px`.

With `body`, I know that it's actually not the `body` whose background is visible, it's the `html` that reverse inherits the background of `body`. So, it's kind of similar to setting it on the `html`.

But my doubt is how does it occupy the full viewport when it has no content or any heights specified?

And it seems that this behavior is only with the `background` property because adding a `border` makes it really clear that the `height` of `html` is `8px` only.

```css
html {
  background: hotpink;
  border: 2px dotted rebeccapurple;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**~ [Per W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html)**

> The background of the root element becomes the background of the canvas and covers the entire canvas, anchored (for 'background-position') at the same point as it would be if it was painted only for the root element itself. The root element does not paint this background again.

In CSS, values are **never** propagated upward, meaning an element never passes values up to its ancestors. However, there are exceptions to the **upward propagation** rule in HTML:

> background styles that are applied to the body element can be passed to the HTML element, which is the document's root element, therefore, defines the canvas.

**~ **[The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449393195)****

So in your example, the body element is the [root-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html), and as required by the CSS rules from the browser, it loses the initial background style and the new background style applies to the containing canvas, therefore making the entire screen is hot pink.

Comment: So basically it means giving background to `html` will apply it to the entire viewport irrespective of its `height`? I've added one more snippet to my question, please have a look.

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee Yes - because of the **upward propagation** rule in HTML. The `html` selector in CSS represents the greatest ancestor and highest root element - therefore defining the canvas.